# Spring Security - Conceptual question around generated security password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am watching a Udemy Course related to REST services using Spring Boot, Data and Security, when setting up the project I noticed the security password printed when the server starts, generated by Spring Security:

```
Using generated security password: 25b18119-45f0-4d31-99ce-29ba2ccbe3c0
... After restarting
Using generated security password: f75fa549-7856-4fcf-9e70-9f738ad7171d
... After restarting
Using generated security password: 4777e44c-e598-4a2f-b690-ab70b5ca1d4e
...
```

Which makes me wonder two things:

1. How is it possible to another application to consume my services since each time the authorization will have a different password?
2. Is this supposed to be a *development* feature only, and not supposed to be used in production?

Since I did not configure anything more in the course, I still updating the generated security password each time the server is restarted, which is a pain. Is there any related configuration to define a *final* application password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How is it possible to another application to consume my services since each time the authorization will have a different password?

1.1. As you already do (by updating the (client's) password on each container start)

1.2. By providing fixed credentials... (core of your question)

2. Is this supposed to be a development feature only, and not supposed to be used in production? Of course it is a handy development feature, but *can* also be used in production.

To provide fixed credentials, please add `spring.security.user.name` and `spring.security.user.password` properties. (to your configuration/application.properties/.yaml ...)

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#web.security

Answer (score 1):

In SpringBoot you can override default generated password by specifying it in application.property file under 'resources' folder.

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=abcde
```